# Keyboard remain opens when Toolbar back arrow is pressed

Tags: android, toolbar, android-toolbar

I am following below code:-

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // handle arrow click here
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.transition.right_in, R.transition.right_out);


        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

In this when my keyboard is open and I  press my toolbar back arrrow ,the keyboard remain open and activity got finish. I have tried forcefully hiding keyboard in on pause() by callling below method but doesn't look good while transition :-

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Activity activity) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        //Find the currently focused view, so we can grab the correct window token from it.


        View view = activity.getCurrentFocus();
        //If no view currently has focus, create a new one, just so we can grab a window token from it
        if (view == null) {
            view = new View(activity);
        }
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to put in your toolbar back button this code:

```
//Hide keyboard when button was clicked.
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
```

like this:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // handle arrow click here
        if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {

            finish();
            overridePendingTransition(R.transition.right_in, R.transition.right_out);


        }
    //Hide keyboard when button was clicked.
        InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Comment: @Adley- I tried this hiding keyboard after and before finishing activity, the problem is when it return back to previous screen ..It show some white space of keyboard while hiding it which look really ugly as User experience.

Comment: Have you tested in others devices, physical device? This was strange...

Comment: Yes, I have tried with samsung s6 and moto g2..but the result is same which is quite weird.

Comment: Yes... I don't know why. Actually I've never face this problem, so I don't know how I can help you :( If I found any possible solution I tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you getting android home button with `onOptionsItemSelected()` ?
Just do like above :

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            main = new Intent(SettingActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
            main.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_BROUGHT_TO_FRONT);
            finish();

            InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

            startActivity(main);
            overridePendingTransition(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
        }
    });
```

Hope it will help you, Darkball60